# How to clear input after form submission in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to clear input after my form submission get successful. I don't want to use reset button in this case.
I have passed submitted data to api that is in another file.

Please help.

file forgotPassword.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { forgotPassword } from "../../actions/authActions";
import classnames from "classnames";


class ForgotPassword extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email:"",
      errors: {}
    };
  }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };
  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var emailId = {
      email: this.state.email
    };

    this.props.forgotPassword(emailId, this.props.history);

  };
      render(){
    const { errors } = this.state;
     return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s8 offset-s2">
            <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
              <h4><b>Forgot Password</b></h4>
              </div>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.email}
                  error={errors.email}
                  id="email"
                  type="email"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.email
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <span className="red-text">{errors.email}</span>
              </div>

              <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
                <button
                  style={{
                    width: "150px",
                    borderRadius: "3px",
                    letterSpacing: "1.5px",
                    marginTop: "1rem"
                  }}
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable blue accent-3"
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onHandleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = this.state.email;
    this.props.onSearchTermChange(email);
    console.log(email);
    this.setState({
      email: ''
    });
}


}
  ForgotPassword.propTypes = {
  forgotPassword: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { forgotPassword }
)(ForgotPassword);
```

File authaction.js where calling api

```
import axios from "axios";
import setAuthToken from "../utils/setAuthToken";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING} from "./types";

export const forgotPassword = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/forgotpassword", userData)
    .then(res => 
      console.log("forgot password",res)
      )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

After successfull result on api I'm unable to clear input in forgot password form component.
Please let me know if any other way to do this task.I'm a newbie in react.
Many thanks for help.

Comment: Can you please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is a very broad question.  We know nothing about how the form is populated or what data structures you are using.  Show us your code and tell us what you have tried to do.

Comment: @Woodrow added files and explain in brief. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Changing the value of a TextInput component**

You can change the context of the input after an onPress event coming from a button.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text : "Username"
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        // TextInput gets its value from the state.text above.
        <TextInput value={this.state.text } style={{borderColor:"black", border:1}}/>
        // Button calls the function in onPress when it is pressed, which cleans up the state.text
        <Button title="CLEAN" onPress={() => this.setState({text: ""})} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Faith.  I don't want a button to clear input. I want input clear after successfull submission on api.